# running java application from command line

Tags: java

I have an eclipse project which I want to run from the command line in ubuntu. After searching on the internet I am trying the following command.

```
java -cp . com.abc.utils.MyClassName
```

I issue this command from the directory that eclipse is using to store all the class files. But I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abc/utils/MyClassName

what am I doing wrong and how to run the application from the command line ?

Comment: read [this](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html). It will help you...

Comment: Also when you have Eclipse, why you are running on command line?

Answer (score 1):

Your command is right. You have missed something. Please check that

**1.** You have compiled your code and the `MyClassName.class` file is created in `classes/com/abc/utils/` directory.

**2.** You are running this command from proper directory. Your current directory should be classes directory where your `com` directory is located. If it's not then switch to `classes` directory

`$cd /path/to/project/folder/classes/`

Hope that helps.

Additionally if you want to learn how eclipse automatically places `.class` and `.java` files then try compiling a multi-package application by yourself.

`$javac -d` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run .class files aka compiled java files. 
So you first need to compile your java file with the 'javac' command. This will generate a .class file.
Then you can run the java class file with the 'java' command.

Comment: but I have already compiled that code from eclipse and I am trying to run the compiled .class file that is inside the classes/com/abc/utils/ folder

Comment: try removing the -cp and without the . (dot)

Comment: Thanks dbf, its working now that I run this command from the classes directory.

Answer (score 0):

you should set class path first